# Plotting errors on a bar plot from a second Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe with rows for variables and columns holding the values for those variables from different runs.

And I can plot this just fine in a bar plot using df.plot(kind='bar'). But I also have the errors for each of those values in a separate dataframe. How could I go about adding vertical error bars on the existing bar plot using the errors stored in a second dataframe?

Currently, I plot the data with just

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

And the DataFrame I'm plotting looks like:

```
     run1 run2 run3
var1 1.0  2.0  3.0
var2 1.0  2.0  3.0
```

I then have another DataFrame with the same structure but the values are the percent errors associated with each run/var combination.

I don't know how to include the errors DataFrame (let's call it edf) as the vertical error bar on the existing plot.

Comment: can you add code examples with a sample of your data? That will help others solving your problem.

Comment: I've edited the post to include more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. When I plot with

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar',yerr=edf)
```

It seems to be doing what I want.